# Process runs in Powershell Prompt but not as a scheduled task?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, privileges, windows-task-scheduler

```
$taskTrigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 2:50PM

$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
   -Execute "powershell.exe" `
   -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File `"<path>\tiddlywikiIIS_schtask_rsync\backup.ps1`""

$taskName = "Backup Stuff"
$description = "Rsync Backup Stuff"

Register-ScheduledTask `
   -TaskName $taskName `
   -Action $taskAction `
   -Trigger $taskTrigger1 `
   -Description $description

$taskPrinciple = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "Domain\someadmin" -RunLevel Highest
$taskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Principal $taskPrinciple -Settings $taskSettings
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -User $taskPrinciple.UserID -Password '******'
```

```
# Pull the creds for a user account that has WSL installed on it.
$cred = Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"

$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property @{
 RedirectStandardError = $true
 RedirectStandardOutput = $true
 UseShellExecute = $False
 UserName = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Username
 Domain = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
 Password = $cred.Password
 WorkingDirectory = "C:\windows\"
 FileName = "wsl"
 Arguments = "-d Ubuntu-18.04 -e rsync -av --delete /mnt/c/stuff/ /mnt/o/stuff_bk/"
 WindowStyle = "Hidden"
}

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $psi
$p.WaitForExit()
$p.ExitCode
```

**backup.ps1**

I have the code above running in a scheduled task that is running with an (domain?) administrator account.

When it returns from the scheduled task it's `$p.ExitCode` is `-1073741502` but if I run the same code in an administrative powershell prompt run as the same (domain?) administrative account it runs fine.

It makes me thing that it has something to do with the `Local Security Policy` as I remember there being some sort of "Allow Batch Execution" or "Delegate" or some such privilege in there that prevents any group or user not included from running something as a batch job.

I also found the following log in the Event Viewer:

Okay, so I found a log entry in the System Log with a Source of `Application Popup`, `Event ID` 26 which reads:

```
EventData -> Caption: `wsl.exe - Application Error`

EventData -> Message: `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).  Click OK to close the application.`
```

Comment: "...that prevents any group or user not included from running something as a batch job." That's correct, but I assume `-UserId "Domain\someuser"` does have some permissions over the computer running this task, else you'll need to add that service account to `Log on as a batch job` on `secpol.msc > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment`. Judging by the Event log your error is not related to that because if the account did not have permissions to run as a job the task would have never ran so `wsl.exe` would have never ran either.

Comment: One question, is `-UserId "Domain\someuser"` the same user that exported the credentials on `$cred = Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"`? I'm not familiar with `Get-StoredCredential` but if this works same as `Import-CliXml` for retrieving PSCredential objects and if that user did not export those creds then there is your issue.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  so you are saying I need to run a powershell window as `Domain\someuser` and see if the `Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"` returns what is expected for running the `wsl` command?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon okay, so I tried using two separate powershell windows to pull `Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"` with both (`Domain\someuser`) and

Comment: I'm saying that if `Get-StoredCredential` works the same way as `Export-Clixml` for exporting PSCredentials, then the only one that can retrieve the credential file is the user that exported that credential file and on the same computer where those credentials were exported. Hope it makes sense. Clixml creates a self-signed cert for this matter.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon okay, so I tried using two separate powershell windows to pull `Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"` with both (`Domain\someadmin) and the the account that is used to call `wsl`...(what was obtained from `some-non-admin-credz`, we'll call it (`Domain\user`)

The Powershell task for `backup.ps1` is run by `Domain\someadmin` and when `wsl` is called it uses `Domain\user` to call it.

In the test Powershell window logged in as `Domain\user` `Get-StoredCredential -Target "some-non-admin-credz"` returns nothing, but in `Domain\someadmin` it returns a credential.

Comment: Then the service account running the scheduled task would have to be `Domain\someadmin` using your example above, OR, you would have to export those credentials again impersonated as `Domain\user`

Comment: I thought I did export the `Domain\user` credentials in the `Domain\someadmin` account (see my previous comment).  

Maybe I just need to make a service account; but then that service account needs to have wsl installed on it (which is why I did this in the first place, I didn't want to install yet another WSL distro on the `Domain\someadmin` profile)

Comment: I see, if the task is running with `Domain\someadmin` and that user can retrieve those credentials then the issue is something else. You could `$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'` at the top and use `try { all backup.ps1 code here } catch { $errormsg=$_ | select *; $errormsg > "$psscriptroot\error.txt"}` so when the task run you could understand better what is erroring out.